# Convert Blob data to Raw buffer in javascript or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, buffer, jspdf

I am using a plugin [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which generates PDF and saves it to local file system. Now in jsPDF.js, there is some piece of code which generates pdf data in blob format as:-

```
var blob = new Blob([array], {type: "application/pdf"});
```

and further saves the blob data to local file system. Now instead of saving I need to print the PDF using plugin [node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer).

Here is some sample code to do so

```
var fs = require('fs'),
var dataToPrinter;

fs.readFile('/home/ubuntu/test.pdf', function(err, data){
    dataToPrinter = data;
}

var printer = require("../lib");
printer.printDirect({
    data: dataToPrinter,
    printer:'Deskjet_3540',
    type: 'PDF',
    success: function(id) {
        console.log('printed with id ' + id);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.error('error on printing: ' + err);
    }
})
```

The `fs.readFile()` reads the PDF file and generates data in raw buffer format.

**Now what I want is to convert the 'Blob' data into 'raw buffer' so that I can print the PDF.**

Answer (score 30):

If you are not using NodeJS then you should know that the browser does not have a Buffer class implementation and you are probably compiling your code to browser-specific environment on something like browserify. In that case you need [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-to-buffer) that converts your blob into a Buffer class that is supposed to be as perfectly equal to a NodeJS `Buffer` object as possible (the implementation is at [feross/buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer)).

If you are using `node-fetch` (not OP's case) then you probably got a blob from a response object:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const response = await fetch("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
const blob = await response.blob();
```

This blob is an internal implementation and exists only inside `node-fetch` or `fetch-blob` libraries, to convert it to a native NodeJS `Buffer` object you need to transform it to an arrayBuffer first:

```js
const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
```

This buffer object can then be used on things such as file writes and server responses.

Answer (score 9):

For me, it worked with the following:

```
const buffer=Buffer.from(blob,'binary');
```

So, this buffer can be stored in Google Cloud Storage and local disk with fs node package.

I used blob file, to send data from client to server through ddp protocol (Meteor), so, when this file arrives to server I convert it to buffer in order to store it.

Comment: Tried this and receive `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Blob`

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Try `await blob.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => Buffer.from(arrayBuffer, "binary"))`

Answer (score 3):

```
           var blob = new Blob([array], {type: "application/pdf"});

            var arrayBuffer, uint8Array;
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function() {
                arrayBuffer = this.result;
                uint8Array  = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

                var printer = require("./js/controller/lib");
                printer.printDirect({
                    data: uint8Array,
                    printer:'Deskjet_3540',
                    type: 'PDF',
                    success: function(id) {
                        console.log('printed with id ' + id);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.error('error on printing: ' + err);
                    }
                })
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

This is the final code which worked for me. The printer accepts uint8Array encoding format.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
var blob = new Blob([array], {type: "application/pdf"});
var buffer = new Buffer(blob, "binary");
```

Comment: What does this "binary" denote ? Is this the type format of buffer ?

Comment: It specifies the encoding of the input string.

Comment: You mean to say here 'array' is of "application/pdf" format and what 'blob' is generated is of "binary" format.

Comment: BLOB(**B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject) is a collection of binary data stored in an entity. In your particular case, this entity is a string. If you want to create a buffer from that string, you should  specify it's encoding int buffer constructor function. That is what I mean :)

Comment: Ok what other formats does BLOB supports ? And particularly where and in what scenarios are these blob and buffer are used. What is difference between them in simple terms. 

Actually I am new to this encoding and decoding techniques. So its shaking my head. Would be thankful if you provide me some helpful link from where I can learn about them in detail and perform encoding and decoding as per my need in future.

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers

Comment: Today after reaching back to my work place I tested the solution with my printer but the buffer data which I provide to printer is putting the printing job on hold. Please look into this what else I could try out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97359/discussion-between-kamaldeep-singh-and-lazarev-alexandr).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on NodeJs.  I am getting an error: `Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`